# Add a default WP comment form to forum template

Tags: plugin-development, comment-form

I've learned that it is possible to add a default comment to the custom post type:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comments_template

However, what if in case of not custom post type?

I would like to add a default comment form to forum template instead of forum editor, and they do not use custom post type.

So the topics and posts are not stored in `wp_posts` table, they have their own tables for topics and posts.

How can I add a default WP comment to this forum template?